# Count number of posts in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, count

I'm trying to create a menu in cake php where I can also know how many articles are inside the section, should I use a manual query, or does exist some existing method to do it?

```
My site menu:
- Works (12)
- Photos (35)
- Stuff (7)
- Contacts
```

My problem is also I didn't get how I can access to data like this for every view, this should be a main menu, so I should use this in every view but If i put it in `default.ctp`, every model deosn't exist, because I cannot access it from a view.

Does exist some page which talks about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since those are separate models that are not related to each other, you'll need to do a manual count.

```
$this->Model->find('count');
```

**EDIT**

Ok, so looks like you are talking about different models.

If this is used in a menu, that means it will be shown in all pages.

You have two ways of doing this.

You can do it by having an [AppController](http://book.cakephp.org/view/957/The-App-Controller) for you application. Basically, you can put this code in the beforeRender method so it runs everytime your a request is rendered

```
function beforeRender() {
   App::import('Model', array('Work', 'Photo', 'Stuff'));
   $work = new Work();
   $workCount = $work->find('count');

   //do the same for the other

   $this->set('workCount', $workCount);
}
```

Have a look at this for more details on callbacks : http://book.cakephp.org/view/977/Controller-Methods#Callbacks-984

Secondly, you can do this via a helper. You can put the same code (that is inside the `bforeRender`) into a helper, and you can call the helper method.

You can look here for more info on creating a helper : http://book.cakephp.org/view/1097/Creating-Helpers

Comment: Doing so will create an extra call for each row returned from the original query.  By using the `CounterCache` behavior, a count attribute (`article_count`) in the _parent_ model (`Section`) will be updated every time a new child (`Article`) is added.  Since writes are likely to occur far less often than reads, using `CounterCache` will put less drag on the database.

Comment: @Andrew, I think you misunderstood the question. The OP is talking about a site menu where the models have no relation to each other. CounterCache can only be used when you have related models. Calling a count is the preferred option here, since A) Models are unrelated B) You really only want to get the total number of rows.

Comment: How can I use one menu like this for all sections? I cannot access to `$this->Model->find('count');` from the default view `default.ctp`

Comment: @JohnP My understanding is that the relationship is: `Section hasMany Article` and `Article belongsTo Section`.  He has a few Sections: "Works", "Photos", "Stuff", and "Contacts".  The "Works" `Section` has 12 `Articles`, "Photos" 35, etc.  If this is the case, `CounterCache` is the way to go.  If not, you are correct that I have misunderstood the original question.

Comment: @Andrew, CounterCache is the way to go if that is how it's organized. The OP will need to go more details. @vittorio If this menu shows up in all your pages, then you'll have to import the models in at run time using `App::import('Model', array('Work', 'Photo', ....))`. We need more information on how you've organized your models

Comment: I've just started with `cakephp`, I've read all the book, and I've just organized them like the guide says, a `model/controller/view` for `Work`, `Photo` and for `Stuff` (contacts is static). The site is very simple, but I find difficult to do simple things like counting every article per model and be viewed in the main menu, which contain the contents list which are `Work`, `Photo` and `Stuff`. Where should I put `App:import...`?

Comment: @vittorio stick with it, cakePHP becomes very easy to use once you wrap your head around how to do it the 'cake' way. I've added clarifications and references

Answer (score 0):

The CounterCache behavior will help you out:
http://book.cakephp.org/view/1033/counterCache-Cache-your-count