# How can i get the count of the loop in cakephp

Tags: cakephp-2.1

How can i get the count of the loop in cakephp

```
[Book] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 48
                                [bookmaster_id] => 6
                                [condition] => not bad
                                [comments] => not bad
                                [isArchived] => 
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 50
                                [bookmaster_id] => 6
                                [condition] => ok
                                [comments] => ok
                                [isArchived] => 
                            )

                    )
```

i want to get the value of count of arry book

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771257/count-number-of-posts-in-cakephp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this array is called $books

```
count($books)
```

Unless you want to do the count in the database in which case use `find('count', array..)`

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html

Comment: How can i get the [1] => Array and [bookmaster_id] => 6 to get the last. supose my count value is 2 i want to display the details of a[2]

Comment: `pr(end($books['Book']));`

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the direct parent index in the array: 
if you just do `count($books);` the output will be 1

try

```
pr(count($books['Book']));
//Output 2
```